# Which is the basic functioning in MQL5?

Tags: mql5

I would like to know how to buy and sell forex in MQL5 according to some variables that I have established in a python script, which can be saved in a text file.

But what I want mainly is to know how to buy and sell for example AUDCAD and establish a "take profit" of 1.1073 and a "stop loss" to a 1.1115 for example.

If you can provide me a sample code and a site where I can inform myself it would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: `https://www.mql5.com/en/docs` is the official page. You can download and install MT5 then open Editor and check the sample expert advisors and scripts in it.

Answer (score 0):

In mql5 and mql4, an expert advisor is the term they use for an automated trading robot. It will continue to run according to your variables. A little C++ knowledge goes a long way when using mql5. Also for simple examples try https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCokIBdJXNOSOeYkKDvENWYA

Chances are most strategies have been coded before and there are many examples in the  [mql5 Codebase](https://www.mql5.com/en/code/mt5/experts)

If the only variables are stop loss and take profit. You may choose to write a script, which will run once only as soon as it is attached to the chart.